# override : textBox1.Text.ToString()

Tags: c#, textbox, overriding

How to override? ToString()

```
 textBox1.Text.**ToString()**
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, to overload the Text property you'd have to inherit from TextBox yourself, which I doubt you want to do

An easier solution would be creating an extension method for string to do what you want:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    ToSpecialString(this string)
    {
         //do your special ToString() here
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, extension method is probably best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Why on earth would you want to? Text is already a string.

If you need to format the string differently, use String.Format(...), or a custom method you don't need to override the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

We are both override :

```
   class Class1:TextBox
{
    public Class1()
    {

       // this.Text.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ("mystring");
    }

    //protected override Text.tostrong()
    //{

    //}
}
```

Comment: You are overriding TextBox.Tostring(), where you should be overriding TextBox.Text. And you don't need to call ToString - Text is already a string !